# Why isnt this string parsing function working?

Tags: javascript

I created a function to delete the spaces out of a string and return the strings length with out spaces, however the function is deleting more then just the spaces. Also is there a better way of accomplishing this, assuming this function can be fixed.

```
let string="This string is going to lose characters";

function charLength(str){
    let strArray=str.split("");
    let output="";

    for(let i=0; i < strArray.length; i++){
        if(strArray[i]===" "){
            strArray.splice(strArray[i],1);
        }
        else{
            output+=strArray[i];
        }
    }
    return output.length // + " " output, if I were to add this you would see its deleting characters
}

charLength(string);//returns "27 Thistringsoingooseharacters", not "33 Thisstringisgoingtolosecharacters"
```

Comment: The reason why some characters get lost will become evident if you try your function in this [Javascript tutor](http://pythontutor.com/javascript.html#mode=edit). You will see live how `splice` transforms the array inside the loop and thus changes the value of the indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you remove a character from the string you'll have to go back one step (`i--`) st the loop won't skip a character (`for(... ; i++)`). Like this:

```
if (strArray[i] === " ") {
  strArray.splice(strArray[i], 1);
  i--; // ge back one step if we remove one character.
}
```

**Snippet:**

```js
let string = "This string is not going to lose characters";

function charLength(str) {
  let strArray = str.split("");
  let output = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
    if (strArray[i] === " ") {
      strArray.splice(strArray[i], 1);
      i--;
    } else {
      output += strArray[i];
    }
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(charLength(string));
```

**If you want to count characters that are not spaces:**

Then just make a counter that will count the characters that are not spaces like this:

```js
let string = "This string is not going to lose characters";

function charLength(str) {
  let counter = 0;                        // the counter
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {  // for each character in the string
    if(str.charAt(i) !== ' ')             // if the character is not a space
      counter++;                          // increment the counter
  }
  return counter;
}

console.log(charLength(string));
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why characters get lost, is because the list is modified inside the loop.

```
for(let i=0; i < strArray.length; i++){
    if(strArray[i]===" "){
        strArray.splice(strArray[i],1);  // Items are removed here
    ...
```

When you remove an character `i`, the next character will take its place.

You could maybe use the `replace` function instead like this:

```
string.replace(/ /gi, "").length
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex.

```
var str = 'This string is going to lose characters';

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(/\s/g, '');

console.log('Substitution result: ', result.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is much simpler than you are doing. You can just use the **[`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** string method which can take a string literal to replace or a regular expression.

```js
function charLength(str){

    // Create a new string that is the same as the passed in one, but with the spaces stripped out
    // The syntax / / denotes a regular expresion (regEx) object 
    // The s+ denotes to look for one or more spaces in a row
    // The g denotes a global search and replace througout the string 
    var newStr = str.replace(/\s+/g, "");

    console.log("\"" + str + "\" has: " + str.length + " characters."); 
    console.log("\"" + newStr + "\" has: " + newStr.length + " characters."); 
}

charLength("This string is going to lose characters");
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex: str.replace(" ","") is already doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this line here:

`strArray.splice(strArray[i],1);`

Try using this:

`strArray.splice(strArray[i],0);`

Just replaces the `1` with `0`

Answer (score 1):

You could use eiter a regular expression for filtering space

```js
var string = "This string is going to lose characters",
    result = [...string].filter(RegExp.prototype.test.bind(RegExp('[^ ]'))).join('');

console.log(result);
console.log(result.length);
```

Or just test for space.

```js
var string = "This string is going to lose characters",
    result = [...string].filter(a => a !== ' ').join('');

console.log(result);
console.log(result.length);
```